# NullReferenceException on a Label in a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with some labels, they all work fine except the last one leading to NullReferenceException.
Probably there is a banal sintax mistake... but i can't see it!

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ticketrep1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="TicketsRep_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="tksubject" Style="font-weight:bold;" />
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="breadctrail" Style="font-weight:bold;" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void TicketsRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Label tksubject = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("tksubject");
            tksubject.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            tksubject.ID = "tksubject" + Ticket.idTicket;
            tksubject.Text = Ticket.oggetto;

            Label breadctrail = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("breadctrail");
            breadctrail.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            breadctrail.ID = "breadcrumbtrail" + Ticket.idTicket;
            breadctrail.Text = Ticket.categoria.ToString();
    }
}
```

NullReferenceException appears in the first line after declaration:
breadctrail.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

so I tried to comment it and the error simply pass to the second line.
breadctrail appears Null.

Thank you all.

**Edit** for "possible duplicate":
Of two (and more) labels with apparently the same syntax, only one gives an error. Why?

Thank you again.

Comment: Probably `e.Item` doesn't have any `Control` named "breadctrail". Try to double check that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: look at the registration of the event handler. what is sender value? what is the e value in your debug session?

Comment: Do you know what `ClientIDMode.Static` does? Hint: you cannot have multipe controls with the same ID on a page...

Answer (score 0):

Simply this code below gives you null:

```
Label breadctrail = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("breadctrail");
```

It cannot find label with name `breadctrail`.

You can do this:

```
Label breadctrail = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("breadctrail");

if (breadctrail != null) {
   breadctrail.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
   breadctrail.ID = "breadcrumbtrail" + Ticket.idTicket;
   breadctrail.Text = Ticket.categoria.ToString();
} else {
   // Do something when there is no label with this name
}
```

Comment: But why?
  That label is in the same position as the previous one!

Comment: Seems that for some reason it is not. That's why it's a good practice to check whether the object you get is null or not.

Comment: @Dizi0 But how can we know about your UI